# Should this be autoreleased? or is there a way to do it manually?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

Hello i was wondering if someone could give me a bit of advice on memory management.

I have the following:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)addAllObjectesInbetween:(NSMutableArray*)betweenTheTwo{

    NSMutableArray* toReturn = [betweenTheTwo mutableCopy];
    [toReturn insertObject:@"oneObject" atIndex:1];

    return toReturn;
}
```

Now I know that because I am making a mutableCopy that I must release `toReturn` but I am not sure how to do that because it is being returned to a different function. I dont want to release it be for it is sent, but if I try to release it afterwards it just doesn't get called. So i was thinking of adding `autorelease` to the `mutableCopy` but I'm not sure if that is the best thing to do... Could someone lend me a hand here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the best thing to do. You can also add it while returning:

```
return [toReturn autorelease];
```

That's because by convention, if your method does not begin with `init` or (contains) `copy` it must return an autoreleased object. If you want to return a +1 object, change your method name to keep it consistent.

Comment: It seems if i add `[toReturn autorelease];` it breaks... I think I need to do some more investigation. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JamesDunay: Then something else is wrong. You should be calling autorelease like sidyll recommends. Try running "Product->Analyze" on your app to see if it turns up any memory issues in surrounding code for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should either autorelease `toReturn`, or rename your function to start with `copy`, like `copyAllObjectsInBetween:`, or `mutableCopy`, like `mutableCopyAllObjectsInBetween:`.

Comment: But even then I still have a leak when I create toReturn, how might I deal with it. Also please see above comment, as i have tried to autorelease it with no luck, thanks!

Comment: Maybe I got it, I tried retaining the returned array along with autorelease, and it seems to work now i just gotta check for leaks!

Comment: @JamesDunay: You're hiding another bug. The retain+autorelease isn't necessary and is just leaking the object which is why you're not having any other problems.